# How to filter tr last child and not first child

Tags: css, css-selectors

See the example below. Is it possible to apply the bottom border to the `<tr>` in the `<thead>`, by using CSS selectors?

**Edit:** It is the only row there. There is also the possibility of no `<thead>` and `<tbody>` at all.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align: top;
}
tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tables</h2>
<table>
    <caption>Optional table caption.</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)/[`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) pseudo classes to prevent the element from being selecting if it is the only child:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/w2rvjcoq/)

```
tr:last-child:not(:only-child) {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

In this instance, you could also swap `:only-child` out with `:first-child` since you want to negate the first child.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjcLokpz/)

```
tr:last-child:not(:first-child) {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

---

You could also just narrow the selector down so that only `tr` elements within the `tbody` are selected:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxjgt6tw/)

```
tbody tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

..or you could just explicitly set a `border` on the `tr` element within the `thead`..

Answer (score 1):

```
thead{border-bottom:1px solid #f00;}
```

It is as simple as that